# Unable to get json from axios

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

Newbie in JS.

I want to get the json response from axios requet

```
const activities = Axios.get("https://api.github.com/events").then(response => response.data);
console.log(activities);
```

But I do not understand why it is still showing `Promise {<pending>}` in console.

Comment: can you add more code here ? 
to acheive this you need to learn how promise works or await/async.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that `Axios.get()` returns a promise. You can apply a `.then()` callback to the Promise to process what was resolved by the promise.

Here is what you can do:

```
Axios.get("https://api.github.com/events").then(response => {
    const activities = response.data;
    console.log(activities);
});
```

You can also use newer `async/await` depending on version of node you are using:

```
const foo = async () => {
    const response = await Axios.get("https://api.github.com/events");
    const activities = response.data;
    console.log(activities);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain ? To my understanding applying the `then` callback to a Promise will result in its resolution.

Comment: @RaheelKhan No. You can not assign the the return value of a resolved promise. What you want to do can be done using async and await.

Comment: I tried your first approach and now the `activities` variable is undefined outside the axios scope

Comment: Does it means that I have to do all my operations inside the callback ?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, you can use async/await keywords to make your code look 'flat'